# Как добавить проверку логина и пароля?

Tags: php, http, mysql

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Текст, отправляемый в том случае,
    если пользователь нажал кнопку Cancel';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>Вы ввели пароль {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']}.</p>";
}
?>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сюда добавить проверку логина и пароля? Спасибо.

Comment: воспользоваться поиском по форуму, такая тема была и даже больше того раскрыто как сделать разлогинивание!

Comment: Спасибо. Я бы не отказался от линка)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Поиск по форуму](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search/?q=WWW-Authenticate&t=question) Примерно такая ссылка

Comment: Я прошу прощения за свою тупость. Но не могу найти,то что мне нужно